# how to filter various mime file types using javascript

Tags: javascript

here i am having a file upload function where i am having various file types like

```
1.jpg,2.jpeg,3.png,4.jpeg
```

here how can i filter these file types like suppose if i have two file with .jpeg files and like above example then it has to show  .jpeg,.png,.jpg and if the all the file type are .jpeg,jpeg,jpeg then it should display '+'

below is the logic i applied but it work if i defined a certain extension

```
var filelist = ['woohoo.txt', 'aha.pdf', 'wahoo.txt'];
var extension = '.txt';

var x = filelist.filter(function(file){
    return file.indexOf(extension) !== -1;
});

console.log(x); //
```

here i dont know which extension will be there more so dynamically can it be grouped

Comment: Just to bring your attention , what if the file was my.txt.exe . it'll be accepted as well :) . Please make sure to check after the last dot .

Comment: You can use `file.split(".").pop()` to get the extension

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an array of the all the extension and then filter them out.

```js
var filelist = ['woohoo.txt', 'aha.txt', 'wahoo.txt','wahoo.abc.txt'];

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

var extensions = filelist.map(function(file){
    return file.split('.')[file.split('.').length-1];
});

var unique = extensions.filter( onlyUnique ); 

console.log(unique.length >1 ? unique.toString() : unique.toString()+'+'); //
```

Comment: what about other file types if i include ?

Comment: In the .map function we are making an array of all the extenstion from filelist array by spliting them ('.'). You can add more sanity check to see if length of file.split('.') is greater than 0,